# E_Fail Error While reading the value from the opc server OpcNetApi

Tags: c#, dcom, opc

I have a softing datafeed opc server running on my 64bit machine. Also my windows services is running on the same machine.(i.e., locally) I have a windows services which reads the tags value from the opc server every sec. The opc server is setup with the plcs.

It reads the value fine but, in between it also throws the E_Fail error while reading every approx 5 mins or 20 mins.

Can anyone help me here why its happening?
Can anyone explain me this error E_Fail what does it actually mean?